What the best practice for using "use client" when using MUI theme
I just wonder, if I have a simple MUI component that only for showing the data from parent, can I just keep my component as server component while I need custom the component through theme?
I can do like this using the hardcode color as server component
import { Box } from "@mui/material";

const CustomComp = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Box height={100} width={100} sx={{ backgroundColor: "#1976D2" }}>
      {data}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default CustomComp;


but must use the "use client" for access color in theme
"use client";

import { Box, useTheme } from "@mui/material";

const CustomComp = ({ data }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Box
      height={100}
      width={100}
      sx={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.customColor }}
    >
      {data}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default CustomComp;


is there any way to keep my component as a server component or should I just leave it as a client component?
